# Promise and Promise.all(array) executed before array fulfilled

Tags: javascript, function, promise, es6-promise

The `Promise.all(arr).then` callback is executed before the array is fulfilled, so it doesn’t catch its elements. How can I do this properly?

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr.push((function() {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Resolved!");
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    });
  })());
}

Promise.all(arr).then(function() {
  console.log("Done");
});
```

My expect result is:

```
Resolved!
Resolved!
Done
```

But real result is:

```
Done
Resolved!
Resolved!
```

The code above is just an example. I changed the structure like below and the code no longer has a problem, but I should use a `for` loop and `push` because of my application structure.

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Resolved #1");
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Resolved #2");
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
});
var arr = [p1, p2];

Promise.all(arr).then(function() {
  console.log("Done");
});
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from the closure, should be `return new Promise` etc.

Comment: E.g., `arr` is full of `undefined`, not promises. There's also no need for that outer anonymous function at all, simply `arr.push(new Promise ...)` is sufficient.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the function around the new Promise is unnecessary.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate of [Promise.all is returning an array of undefined and resolves before being done](/q/34813147/4642212). That question is using a `.map`, whereas you’re using `.push` in a loop. However, the result of these two approaches is identical, and the fundamental problem is the same: the function you’re using a Promise in doesn’t return anything, so you push nothing but `undefined` in your Array, causing `Promise.all` to resolve immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [georg said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616351/javascript-promise-and-promise-allarray-executed-before-array-fulfilled/36616458#comment60829165_36616351), you're just not putting the promises in `arr`, because you never return anything from the anonymous function you've wrapped around `new Promise`. That function is also completely unnecessary, so:

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      log('resolved !');
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  }));
}

Promise.all(arr).then(function() {
  log("Done");
});

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

If the function is there so you can capture the then-current value of `i`, just ensure you return the promise:

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr.push(function(index) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        log('resolved with ' + index + ' !');
        resolve(index);
      }, 500);
    });
  }(i));
}

Promise.all(arr).then(function() {
  log("Done");
});

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```